# Making use of javascript as a scripting laguage in a c# application

Tags: javascript, c#

I was wondering if its possible to write a c# program with some functions for example i would have something like this:

```
namespace Functions
{
    class Mathematics
    {
        public static float add(float[] x)
        {
            float sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                sum += x[i];
            }

            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

and a directory which looks like this:

```
|_c#
    |_//c# code in here
|_Scripts
    |_script.js //my file with a script
```

after running the c# application it would run the javascript code and call the correct functions

Comment: Write a websocket/http nodejs server and send JS code to it to execute and return JSON? seems pretty easy. seems faster with many calls then creating nodejs process for each invocation

Comment: i was thinking of writing a game engine in c# and then using js as the scripting language so i think that relying on this would be problematic in matter of performance

Answer (score 2):

You could use some .NET JS interpreter for example:
https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

Comment: do you maybe have an idea what clearscript is and could explain it